# Class 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Engine\BranchPruner' not found when using Export Maatwebsite Excel Laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to export the data using maatwebsite/excel, but i got error Class 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Engine\BranchPruner' not found, when using Export Maatwebsite Excel

i tried composer update but still not working

SOLVED [deleting vendor and running composer install again].

Comment: Kindly post your code here too in order to get the best solution as one cannot suggest an appropriate solution without viewing your current implementation.

Comment: Try deleting `vendor` and running `composer install` again. Check if there are any errors (and share them here if applicable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to export data

```
return Excel::download((new MyDataExport()), 'MyDataExport.' . 'csv');
```

While the class `MyDataExport` here should have following structure

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class MyDataExport implements FromArray, WithHeadings
{
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Id',
            'Name',
        ];
    }

    public function array(): array
    {
        $data = callSomeFuctionToGetData();
        $rows = [];
        foreach ($data as $row) {

            $tempRow = [];
            $tempRow['Id'] = $row->id;
            $tempRow['Name'] = $row->name;
           
            array_push($rows, $tempRow);
        }

        return $rows;
    }

}
```

Comment: there is my code,  i still got same error